# Using a hook from a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code:

```
class IPT_FSQM_Form_Creation_Hook {
public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'ipt_fsqm_form_created', array( $this, 'hook_into_form_creation' ), 10, 1 );
}
   function hook_into_form_creation( $data ) {
   // Global config and db variables
   global $wpdb, $ipt_fsqm_info;
      $wpdb->insert( $ipt_fsqm_info['form_table'], array(
        'name' => 'I did this',
      ) );
   }  
}
```

The hook created in the plugin is as follows:

```
$return_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
do_action( 'ipt_fsqm_form_created', $return_id, $this );
```

My custom hook doesn't get triggered how I have it. I know it doesn't get triggered because nothing gets inserted into the database. When I change the code to the following it inserts the data but then I don't have access to any of the data in the `$this` variable:

```
add_action( 'ipt_fsqm_form_created', 'hook_into_form_creation' );
function hook_into_form_creation( $data ) {
// Global config and db variables
global $wpdb, $ipt_fsqm_info;
  $wpdb->insert( $ipt_fsqm_info['form_table'], array(
  'name' => 'I did this',
  ) );
}
```

How can I get the data in `$this` and still get access to my hook?

Comment: Where do you run `add_action( 'ipt_fsqm_form_created', array( $this, 'hook_into_form_creation' ));`? Are you running it inside of the `__construct` method of your class or another method that gets called early?

Comment: @NikolaIvanovNikolov I updated my question to show the class construct.

Comment: do you initialize this class on time compared to when the `ipt_fsqm_form_created` action is triggered? I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: @NikolaIvanovNikolov I guess that's what I'm missing. I never initialized it. Where would I initiate it from? The new class that I'm creating is in my plugin and I don't want to update the other plugin to initiate this class because it will get overwritten with upgrades.

Comment: It depends. Does this class do anything else besides hook into this action? If so, then you probably don't even need a class. If it does something else, then if you'll need it initialized on every request, `init` or `plugins_loaded` would probably be good places. As a final measure if none of the above work, you can initialize it right after the class definition.

Comment: @NikolaIvanovNikolov No, it doesn't do anything else right now other than hook into that action. Would I just initialize it  like this `$form_creation_hook = new IPT_FSQM_Form_Creation_Hook();` so I can still get the data from the original hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that the class was not being initialized and therefore the function never attached to the action.

I think you're approaching this the wrong way. The `$this` variable that is available within non-static methods of a class always points to the current class's instance. So using `$this` within your method would actually point at the `IPT_FSQM_Form_Creation_Hook` class instance, and not at the instance of the class that fired the action.

Since you're not using this class for anything else, there's not much of a point in making that class. Instead you can make a regular function and attach that to the action, just like you already did. There's only one difference though:

```
add_action( 'ipt_fsqm_form_created', 'hook_into_form_creation', 10, 2 );
function hook_into_form_creation( $data, $object ) {
    // Global config and db variables
    global $wpdb, $ipt_fsqm_info;
    $wpdb->insert( $ipt_fsqm_info['form_table'], array(
        'name' => 'I did this',
    ) );
}
```

Note the last parameter of `add_action()`: **2**. This defines how many parameters your callback function expects and defaults to 1. Also note that I've now added an `$object` parameter to your function. Use this as you would've used `$this` in your function - it will be the instance of the other plugin's class.

Note that certain properties and methods of `$object` might not be accessible for you(such as private/protected methods and properties) and there isn't really anything you can do, since your function will never be part of the other plugin's class scope.